# Angular karma testing controller

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to figure out these karma tests to test my Angular app. I can figure out simple things. But I am having problems with one that connects to my database.

I am wanting to test the $scope.getMultipleOptions function in the controller below:

```
$scope.options = [];

$scope.getMultipleOptions("form_field_1", $scope.options);

$scope.getMultipleOptions = function (key, opts) {
    var id = key.replace("form_field_", "");

    var promise = DynamicFormFactory.GetData('/DynamicForm/GetMultipleOptions?form_field_id=" + id);

    promise.then(
        function (success) {
        angular.forEach(success, function (o) {
            opts.push(o);
        });
        },
        function (error) {
        // Error
        }
    );
    }
```

This is what my factory/service looks like:

```
dynamicFormApp.factory('DynamicFormFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            GetData: function (url) {
                return $http.get(url)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        }, function (error) {
                            return error;
                        });
            }
}]);
```

And this is what I've done to set up my karma test

```
describe('DynamicFormController', function () {

    beforeEach(module('dynamicFormApp'));

    var $controller;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));


    describe('$scope.getMultipleOptions', function () {
        var $scope, controller;

        beforeEach(function () {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            controller = $controller('DynamicFormController', { $scope: $scope });
            $scope.fields = [];
        });

        it('$scope.getMultipleOptions', function () {
            var key = "form_field_15";

            var expectedResult = [{ desc: "DESCRIPTION", id: "ID" }];

            $scope.getMultipleOptions(key, $scope.fields);

            expect($scope.fields).toEqual(expectedResult);
        });


    });

});
```

The test always fails as $scope.fields is always empty. How do I do this?

Comment: You need $rootScope.$digest() to execute the promise chain. It is preferable to mock DynamicFormFactory.GetData for the spec that tests getMultipleOptions.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction of any examples to mock my service, based on the way my code is structured?